# How to add a marker on a custom google map from an independant js file

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, google-maps-markers

My problem is quite simple to understand, yet I don't seem to find any solution anywhere.

Basically I'm making a game in which user have access to a google map, with custom points set up by me, from a PHP database.

What I'd like to do is : when the user clicks on a button, a new marker appears on the map, but only him on his screen can see it.

I don't know if this new marker should be hardcoded or stored in PHP, and I'd like to know if the js function to add this event could be triggered from a new js file, without all the init map function.

Below is my actual map function, that picks markers from a database :

```
    function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 50.7886994,
      lng: -1.0750918
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var mypos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(mypos);

      var mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mypos,
        map: map,
        title: 'You are here'
      });

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  }
  else {
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }


  var customIcon = {
    character: {
      url: './img/live.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    venue: {
      url: './img/monument.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    music: {
      url: './img/music.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    }
  };

  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 32, 32, 32, 32, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  downloadUrl('./php/parseXML.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
      var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
      var des = markerElem.getAttribute('des');
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

      var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
      var strong = document.createElement('strong');
      strong.textContent = name
      infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
      infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = des
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customIcon[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon,
        shape: shape,
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

    });
  });

        }


  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
      'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
      'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }


      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
```

If you can understand my request, hope you'll be able to help !